# Localization for HTML files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, localization

How can I add localization resource file for .html file?
Any one have idea?

I have done already for aspx pages. But when I am opening html page in designer mode, it does not displaying **Generate Local Resource** option.

Comment: Of course not because plain HTML pages aren't managed/handled/rendered in any way on server side. Client gets what's on disk from server. You have MANY options, just to mention few: multiple HTML pages (one per language, grouped in folders), JavaScript localization (many options, even simple JSON resource files) or an IIS extension to postprocess them (using placeholder for resources to be localized).

Comment: @Adriano Can you give any sample link to which i can refer?

Comment: jQuery + templates and onclient postprocessing...

Comment: @MonikaParekh try Google, there are really too many ways to do that to even mention them all (and actually to provide links we'll just Google for you)

Comment: @MonikaParekh try this link may this help you to understand https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/HTML-Page-Localization

Comment: thanks @Abhishek this link seems really usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aspx pages are generated on the server dynamically, and therefore you can change what is outputted, and support localisation.  `.html` files are static, so you either need to have separate html files for each language (yuck), or change them to be aspx pages and generate them dynamically as you have done your others.

Comment: is this link will help her https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/HTML-Page-Localization